# Eigenvalues and Determinants with variable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Problem Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqP9M.png)

I'm trying to solve this problem and I've managed to solve earlier parts that had to do with the rank depending on the λ and whether A can be inverted but I am not sure how to answer these three questions.

For the first question, I'm clueless, I've been searching for hours and haven't found something.

Then on the second one, I found some similar questions in here but they don't have a variable or that ^3. From what I've gathered so far, I can see that AAT is symmetric and therefore it has real eigenvalues. But I am not sure if λ affects it somehow or if that answer is good enough (suppose we didn't have that ^3) and then what to do with that ^3.

Finally on the third question I haven't spend that much time on it, because I feel like there is a chapter that has to do with AAT, ATA and so on that I might have missed that doesn't revolve around actually calculating (AATA)^5 and then seeing what happens to the determinant but somehow skipping all that with some properties I am not aware of.

Comment: Probably better to write out the problems here than to ask people to chase them somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for the **first problem** the answer is that there are no such matrices, because:

If $A,B,C$ correspond to linear maps $a,b,c$ st $$a:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3,\quad b:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^4, \quad c:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$$

then $BAC$ corresponds to $b\circ a\circ c:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ and you want that to be $1-1$ and onto. But that would mean that $b:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^4$ is onto which is a contradiction.

Comment: Took me some time and a lot of youtube videos ( especially this one:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTKOC3Rst8c ) but finally (I think) I get it!